# How can i make config_providers(some classes) which is a common entity as a global variable so that it can be read by all

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a job written in ruby, i want to make config_provider as a common entity got all 3, because it contains common cong_provider classes.
How can i make config_providers(some classes) which is a common entity as a global variable so that it can be read by all

```
 if conf.get_required(condition) == true

   thresh_dynamic_concept(‘Concept')

     providers(‘Provider Class 1)
     config_providers(’some class')
   end

   thresh_dynamic_concept(‘Concept')

    providers(‘Provider Class 2)

     config_providers(’some class')
   end

   thresh_dynamic_concept(‘Concept’)
     providers(‘Provider Class 3)

 config_providers(’some class')
   end

 end
```

Comment: It looks like you have syntax errors, to begin with.

Comment: I have class name, where its written 'some class'.
i just wanted to give an abstract representation

Comment: I see. But its better to use some arbitrary name that fits in the syntax. Even just `Concept` is fine.